Can requests-aws4auth.AWS4Auth accept three arguments?
I'm trying to connect to AWS via a script. The script works on my colleague's machine, but doesn't on mine, even if I install all of his python packages via pip freeze. I can't even run the example from the requests-aws4auth page:
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
   from botocore.session import Session
   credentials = Session().get_credentials()
   auth = AWS4Auth(region='eu-west-1', service='es',
                refreshable_credentials=credentials)

if I try, I get the following error:
TypeError: AWS4Auth() takes 2, 4 or 5 arguments, 0 given

How can I run said piece of code successfully?
I use requests-aws4auth==1.3.1

Turns out that if the system can't find your credentials, Session().get_credentials() returns None. However, rather the error message you get isn't something informative along the lines of "refreshable_credentials was none", but the rather confusing one printed. Fixing the credentials resolves the issue.

Looks like you're somehow ending in the wrong if-else branch here: https://github.com/tedder/requests-aws4auth/blob/v1.3.1/requests_aws4auth/aws4auth.py#L262
Try to set a breakpoint and print the content of self.refreshable_credentials after L261.
